# Can someone explain me what they did in the proof that every extension of degree 2 is normal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, normal-extension

I consider the following proof that every extension of degree $2$ is normal and I got stuck somewhere:

> Let $K$ be an extension of $F$ with $[K:F]=2$. Then $K=F(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of an irreducible quadratic polonomial $f$ over $F$...

I somehow don't see why $K=F(\alpha)$ can someone explain this to me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It means that a base of $K$ as an $F$-vector space has $2$ elements.

Comment: @aprozz Just take $\alpha$ as any element in $K \setminus F$.

Comment: @JiazeZhang yes this is the definition of $[K:F]=2$ right? but why is then $K$ generated by $\alpha$ over $F$? so I mean that then $K=\{x+y\alpha: x,y\in F\}$ But I don't see this fact. Could you maybe explain this a bit more in details?

Comment: $F(\alpha)$ is by definition the smallest subfield of $K$ which contains the field $F$ and the element $\alpha$. By the tower rule $2=[K:F]=[F:F(\alpha)]\cdot [F(\alpha):F]$. Since $F(\alpha)\ne F$ we have $[F(\alpha):F]>1$, and so we must have $[K:F(\alpha)]=1$, which means $K=F(\alpha)$.

Comment: perfect thanks!